# Laravel using Eloquent and DB in the same Model

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model called `Bar` which extends Laravel's `Eloquent`

```
class Bar extends Eloquent{

}
```

Now the problem is that I need to make some joins between multiple tables and for that I'd like to use the `DB` class from Laravel to improve performance(using eloquent ends up costing me around 750 queries and 20 seconds to load).

Can i use `DB` in the same model that extends `Eloquent`?

If not, should i create another model?

Comment: You can use both Eloquent and DB in a class that extends neither

Comment: Using eloquent relations or the query builder will have almost the same performance. The problem is probably in how you query the relations. Can you post this code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your models should extends `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` not `Eloquent`

Eloquent is basically the ORM laravel uses by default

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Bar extends Model
{
    public function getFooAttribute()
    {
        return \DB::table('bars')->value('foo');
    }
}
```

You can use the `DB` facade almost anywhere to perform Query Builder SQL statements just fine

Hope this helps